# regular expression of number and letters mix

Tags: javascript

My account must have number and letters.And its length range 4 and 8.
**It's not only number and it's not only letters.**

Right ex: a111 ,1a1bb,  aa111a, 111aaa.  Error ex: abcdef, 12345, a123!.

How can I write the Regular Expression.

I tried write that:`([a-z]+[0-9]+[a-z]*){4,10}|([0-9]+[a-z]+[0-9]*){4,10}`.

But it's not match. Where is my error?

Comment: Your expression only matches strings with a minimum length of 8. The shortest strings that can be matched are `a1a1a1a1` and `1a1a1a1a`.

Comment: Please add more of a description on the expected string ex: how many characters etc. If you just want letters and numbers without any other requirements then it is ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ which could be found by [Googleing fairly easy](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/). Replace '+' with '{minDigits, maxDigits}' to control str length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> /^(?=.*[a-z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-z].*)[a-zA-Z\d*]{4,8}$/

```
var filter = /^(?=.*[a-z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-z].*)[a-zA-Z\d*]{4,8}$/; 
var vals = "11aa11";
if (filter.test(vals)){
 alert('working');
 }else {
alert('not working');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:** *update*  `^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,20})$`

```
Here
 ^(
(?=.*\d)    // must contains one digit from 0-9
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])  //must contains one lowercase Uppercase characters
[a-zA-Z0-9]         //match any letter or number previous condition checking
{4,20}           //length at least 4 characters and maximum of 20   
)$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/jP9oC3/2)

Comment: Thanks for your anser. But I only need number and letters.

Comment: It's Matched. Thanks.

Comment: I can't unserstand the (?=.*\d) .  Can you recommend some blogs or articles to me?

Comment: More details [http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var patt = new RegExp("(([A-Za-z][0-9]) |([0-9][A-Za-z])) ([A-Za-z]*[0-9]*){2,6}");
var res = patt.exec(test_str);
```